# Join With Sub query Joining Specific ID

Tags: sql, join, subquery

What I'm trying to achieve is to bring the top 1 CLM000ID of each instance where the CLMSTSID is equal 3.
I'm assuming with the below it will join the top 1 regardless of the CLM00ID.
How can I achieve this?

Table is something like this

```
CLM000ID    |     CLMSTSID
1                  2
1                  3
2                  3



LEFT JOIN UC00LCNTRY0 cntry ON drs.CNTRY0ID=cntry.CNTRY0ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 CLM000ID,LSTPDTS 
            FROM UC07DCLSTTR 
            WHERE CLMSTSID=3
            ORDER BY LSTPDTS DESC) dtclsd ON dtclsd.CLM000ID=c.CLM000ID
LEFT JOIN UC10DSR0000 clmf ON clmf.SR0000ID=c.CLMSFCRID
```

Comment: Each instance of what?  More sample data, desired results, explanation and an appropriate database tag would all help.  Your code mentions three tables (at least) and you haven't explained them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do this in a subquery, then you want `OUTER APPLY`:

```
LEFT JOIN
UC00LCNTRY0 cntry
ON drs.CNTRY0ID = cntry.CNTRY0ID OUTER APPLY
(SELECT TOP 1 CLM000ID,LSTPDTS 
 FROM UC07DCLSTTR dc
 WHERE dc.CLM000ID = c.CLM000ID AND
       dc.CLMSTSID = 3
 ORDER BY LSTPDTS DESC
) dtclsd
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Could you explain what Outer APPLY does?

Comment: @Camus . . . Technically, it implements a *lateral join*.  More practically, it acts like a correlated subquery that can return multiple columns, multiple rows, and is in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

use `max()` aggregation function instead of getting the `top` record.

```
LEFT JOIN UC00LCNTRY0 cntry ON drs.CNTRY0ID=cntry.CNTRY0ID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT MAX(CLM000ID) CLM000ID, LSTPDTS 
            FROM UC07DCLSTTR 
            WHERE CLMSTSID=3 AND CLM000ID=c.CLM000ID
            GROUP BY LSTPDTS) dtclsd ON dtclsd.CLM000ID = c.CLM000ID
LEFT JOIN UC10DSR0000 clmf ON clmf.SR0000ID=c.CLMSFCRID
```

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't very clear. If the top of the CLM000ID is 2 for instance then I don't want to join. Pretty much 3 indicates a specific status (closed). This table works as a tracking table. So it can change from 3 to 2 and vice versa. Grabbing the Max won't indicate that the current status is closed

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a way to accomplish this but using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`

```
SELECT CLM000ID, CLMSTSID, LSTPDTS, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by CLM000ID ORDER BY LSTPDTS DESC)
            FROM UC07DCLSTTR 
            WHERE CLMSTSID=3 
            and CLM000ID in (18)--(2,5,6,10,12,13,15,16,17,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,29,18)          
            ORDER BY LSTPDTS DESC
```